# Update syntax for Access

Tags: ms-access, syntax

I need to update a field (which is currently empty) based on a match with another table.  This should be simple, but my syntax is wrong.

In SQLServer 2005, the syntax would be

```
UPDATE Facilities-NOID
SET Facilities-NOID.ID = Facilities-ID.ID
FROM Facilities-NOID, Facilities-ID
WHERE [Facilities-ID].[Structure ID] = [Facilities-NOID].[Structure ID];
```

Access doesn't like that FROM line, but if I leave it out, it wants each ID.  This should be simple, but I'm not seeing it in the MS help on the Update syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
UPDATE Facilities-NOID 
INNER JOIN Facilities-ID ON Facilities-NOID.[Structure ID] 
    = Facilities-ID.[Structure ID]
SET Facilities-NOID.ID= Facilities-ID.ID
```

You are updating Facilities-NOID based on a match on Structure ID occurring in Facilities-ID.

Comment: Now it's asking for input a Facilities-ID.StructureID  (no space!).

Do I need some sort of select * from Facilities-ID?

Comment: The Jet query optimizer optimizes an explicit JOIN and an implicit join using a WHERE clause exactly the same, so there oughtn't be any difference between whether you use the WHERE clause or the INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the FROM clause completely

```
UPDATE Facilities-NOID
SET Facilities-NOID.ID = Facilities-ID.ID
WHERE [Facilities-ID].[Structure ID] = [Facilities-NOID].[Structure ID];
```

(that's the way that the query builder ends up constructing them)

Comment: When I run the query, it asks for a parameter value.  It wants Facilities-ID.ID.  I want it to update the entire table with values from the other table.

Comment: Have you tried putting brackets around your table names, as in [Facilities-ID].ID? I can't remember which characters Access/Jet doesn't like in names, but maybe the - (as opposed to underscore _) is treated the same as a space? I always use CamelCase, so never have any need for brackets.