# Errors in UPDATE query - VB6 DAO Access

Tags: ms-access, vb6, dao

A simple UPDATE query with INNER JOIN is causing me problems, using VB6 and DAO on an Access .MDB database.

I thought it would be simple, but whatever changes I make generate errors.

My query is:

```
UPDATE work
INNER JOIN emp ON work.ref = emp.ref 
SET work.code1 = emp.code1
```

This generates run-time error 3075 `Syntax error in query expression 'work.ref = emp.ref'`.

I get a similar error with:

```
UPDATE work w
INNER JOIN emp ON w.ref = emp.ref 
SET w.code1 = emp.code1
```

and

```
UPDATE [work] w
INNER JOIN emp ON w.ref = emp.ref 
SET w.code1 = emp.code1
```

and also if I use alias e for table emp.

I cannot use a `FROM` clause, which is not supported in Access (Thanks though @MarkKram)

I have to use DAO 3.51 (old!) in VB6, which cannot easily be changed.

I have tried square brackets around the first reference to `work` as in `UPDATE [work]` (as I need this in a simple `SELECT * FROM [work]`) as well as various combinations with and without square brackets around table names and column names. But still it fails.

Do you have any suggestions please?

```
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
Dim DB As DAO.Database
Dim szSQL As String

Set ws = gWS
Set DB = gWS.OpenDatabase(WorkFile)

szSQL = "UPDATE work INNER JOIN emp ON work.ref = emp.ref SET work.code1 = emp.code1 WHERE work.trancode = 'P'"
DB.Execute szSQL

Set DB = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
```

Comment: Try this instead:.      UPDATE w SET w.code1 = e.code1  from  work w INNER JOIN emp  e ON w.ref = e.ref   w.trancode = 'P'

Comment: @MarkKram [Access syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379242/11683) is different.

Comment: Take a look at this link then:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882212/sql-updating-from-an-inner-join I really don't use Access very much

Comment: Your query is fine if saved in Access or executed directly against it. If you have a pass-through situation, you will need to use a more ANSI version of SQL (`UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ... WHERE...`).

Comment: @Gserg, as I have to use DAO 3.51 - equivalent to Access 97 - more recent Access syntax may not work.

Comment: Try this: `UPDATE work, emp 
SET work.code1 = emp.code1
WHERE  work.ref = emp.ref 
AND work.transcode ='P'`

Comment: Wow, @Rene you are a star. Your suggestion worked a dream - just as I was about to give up. Please post your suggestion as an answer , so that I can accept it. 

This will save me so much work, so many thanks!  :)

Comment: To the person who gave my question a downvote, I would love to know why, so that I can improve next time. As somebody has been able to come up with a solution within a few hours, surely it was not that bad?

Comment: Often dumb downvoters just don't understand the topic of the question.

Comment: This question assumes that the problem had something to do with VB6, DAO, or Access, when the issue was SQL syntax

Comment: @DaveInCaz  The query is not a general SQL query but specific to Access/DAO. I think also the version/platform makes a difference, as the problem query did not work in DAO 3.51, but worked in [MDB Viewer Plus](http://www.alexnolan.net/software/mdb_viewer_plus.htm), which presumably has a different data access mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE work, emp 
SET work.code1 = emp.code1 
WHERE work.ref = emp.ref AND work.transcode ='P'
```